# Pure interface of a class with subclasses

Tags: c++, interface

Lets suppose you want to make an interface of the class Derived and it looks like this:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
      foo();
}

class Base
{
   public:
      tii();
      //many other methods
}
```

How would you do the Interface? How can you make Base::tii visible (and also other methods) to this new interface?

```
class IDerived
{
   public:
      virtual foo() = 0;
      // should I declare here tii() as a pure virtual function?
      // but by doing it now there is ambiguity!
}
```

What is a good strategy?

The new Derived class should look like this....

```
class Derived : public Base, public IDerived
{
    //implement the real thing    
}
```

Comment: Interfaces are not done this way.

Comment: You are doing things backwards: the class should derive from the interface, not the other way round.

Comment: Sorry you are right.. I corrected it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is doing things backwards: the interface should be defined independently of any concrete classes with all pure virtual methods:

```
class IDerived
{
   public:
      virtual void foo() = 0;
      virtual ~IDerived() {} // don't forget to include a virtual destructor
}
```

And the concrete classes will derive publicly from the interface:

```
class Derived : public Base, public IDerived
{
   public:
      void foo();
}
```

If you want `IDerived` to also declare methods that `Derived` inherits from `Base`, you can have `Derived` explicitly implement the method by calling the inherited implementation:

```
class Derived : public Base, public IDerived
{
   public:
      void foo();
      void bar() { Base::bar(); } 
}
```

Comment: But then there will be ambiguity between IDerived::tii and Base::tii

Comment: @Lesswire: I 'm not sure what you mean. There is no `IDerived::tii`.

Comment: I mean right now the method `Derived::tii()` is not visible from `IDerived`. If I add a pure virtual function to `IDerived` then there will be an ambiguity.

Comment: @Lesswire: I see now. Expanded the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

At front, I dislike interfaces (they are grown by other languages than c++).
Anyway, if you have one, it should be complete: Hence have the 'tii() as a pure virtual function'. To resolve the conflict rewrite that function in 'Derived' (forward to Base::tii).